# Blade passing values from view to master and then pass it to header.blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a situation where i have a view file users.blade.php which extends master. and the master includes another file called header.blade.php, i want to pass some data from users.blade to header.blade.

Here is the simplified version of the files

```
/****** Users.blade.php *********/
@extends('shared.master')
@section('title', 'Dashboard')

@section('pagecss')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links to css file" />
@endsection
```

Here is the master.blade.php

```
/******Shared/master.blade.php ********/
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        @include('shared.header')
    </head>
    <body >

        @yield('content')

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the header file

```
/******Shared/header.blade.php ********/
<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to bootstrap" />
@yield('pagecss')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to other files" />
```

**@yield('pagecss') doesn't work in the header.blade, but it does work in master.blade.** Now i cant paste it in master.blade because there are some files which override other files, so it has to be in a specific order. Any ideas how to make the yield work in header.blade?

**EDIT:** 
I do like **Bharat Geleda** approach, i have modified the code to include some heredocs to make it more convenient. But i think its kind of a hack and still looking for a better solution.

```
/********** Users.blade.php ***********/
@extends('shared.master')
@section('title', 'Dashboard')

@section('pagecss')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links to css file" />
@endsection

<?php $pagecss = <<<CSS_FILES
<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to page css" />
CSS_FILES;
?>

/*********** Shared/header.blade.php **********/
@if(isset($pagecss))
    {{-- */ echo $pagecss;/* --}}
@endif
```

Comment: Hey, have you tried the thing that you've asked. I just tried it and it seems to work perfectly as expected actually. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to do this

```
<?php $pagecss = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to css file" />'?>
    /****** Users.blade.php *********/
    @extends('shared.master')
    @section('title', 'Dashboard')
```

master.blade.php would remain the same

```
/******Shared/master.blade.php ********/
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        @include('shared.header')
    </head>
    <body >

        @yield('content')

    </body>
</html>
```

And then in your header file you could do this

```
/******Shared/header.blade.php ********/
<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to bootstrap" />
@if(isset($pagecss))
    {{ $pagecss }}
@endif
<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to other files" />
```

**EDIT: TESTING OUT QUESTION**

**main.blade.php (master in your case)**

```
<html>
<head>
    @include('test.header')
</head>
<body >

@yield('content')

</body>
</html>
```

**header.blade.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to bootstrap" />
@yield('pagecss')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="links to other files" />
```

**users.blade.php**

```
@extends('test.main')

@section('content')
    CONTENT
@endsection

@section('pagecss')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links to css file" />
@endsection
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links to bootstrap" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links to css file" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links to other files" />
</head>
<body >

    CONTENT

</body>
</html>
```

I guess this is as expected.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, i have edited my question and will be looking for a better way. I will accept your answer if i cant find any better solution :)

Comment: yes your edit is exactly what i need, but its not working for me, let me try it again

Comment: Thanks bharat, I just tried it again and its working now. I am not sure, if have been dreaming alot lately :) But really appreciate you taking the time to run this code. You have saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: No issues, All the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple if it's working on homepage and not in inner views, that means you've used it, and **Blade** will take only the higher level and resolve it (include its content where it should be placed within `@yield`).

What I'm trying to say that if you got a `@yield` within your header file and you've used it as `@section('pagecss')` later you got another view as in your case `Users.blade.php` with the same statement `@section('pagecss')` blade won't take the inner one.

***Solution***

**Nice way but foolish:**

create another `@yield` within your shared header blade file and name it as level two or like so. i.e `@yield('pagecss-2')`

**Good way:**

using `@parent`, this directive is going to append (rather than overwriting) content to the layout

as mentioned here within [docs of laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-a-layout)